# Java Android trying to place a 10*10 grid over a bitmap to see how much of a colour is in each grid section

Tags: java, android

to describe my issue I must first discuss what I am trying to do, https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyoV1.png here is an image of a letter with a 10*10 grid over it. For every box in the grid if 1/3 of the pixels are colored a 1 is added to the ArrayList, otherwise a 0 is added. Here is my 3 methods that I have created to do this: https://gist.github.com/VincentMc/7ddf3c282e80bbff7835 BoundBM is a bitmap object with the letter drawn onto it.

Here is an image of my desired output https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjZkc.png

Here is an image of my actual output https://i.stack.imgur.com/sryy8.png

It seems once a 1 is added on a row it is constantly added until it reaches the next row, but I can't seem to see why??

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been at this quite a while, Thanks!

Comment: "For every box in the grid if 1/3 of the pixels are colored a 1 is added to the ArrayList, otherwise a 0 is added" I don't understand this

Comment: Each box of the grid is checked to see if 1/3 of the pixels inside are colored if the amount of pxiels is greater than 1/3 of the total amount of pixels in the box then a 1 is added if it is less than 1/3 a 0 is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the Code-Segmet you offered, i cant see an obvious mistake. But your design is inviting mistakes. To avoid these you may try:

Don't use count as a classwide variable, thou its not relevant for the hole class but only for the method. So make it an return statement, that you dont loose control over it, that it may be set anywhere or is only changed locally in a method.

totalp should not be calculated in every countPixel() method call, because it is a fixed value for your BoundBM. Initialize it in your constructor maybe, or with loading the bitmap.

At last, you know how large your output array is supposed to be, it doesnt make much sense for me, to keep it a list and to add it. Create an 2D array, and write it directly.

Hope it will help
reineke

EDIT: found the mistake!
in code line 27 you set x to 0 and not to the initial value of the input x, so you continue at the wrong position!!

Here is what i would do:

```
final int GRID=10;  
totalp = boundBM.getWidth()/GRID * boundBM.getHeight()/GRID;

//this method now does not need to read boundBM, so it is more opject-oriented
public int countPixels(int x, int y, int h, int w){
    count = 0;
    for (i=x; i<x+w; i++){
        for(k =y; k<y+h; k++){
            if(c != boundBM.getPixel(i, k)) count++;
        }
    }
    //funny thing
    return (count>totalp/3) ? 1 : 0;
}

public void createNeuralInput(){
    int h = boundBM.getHeight()/GRID;
    int w = boundBM.getWidth()/GRID;
    int[][] array= new int[GRID][GRID];
    for(int i = 0; i < GRID; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < GRID ; j++) {
            n1.add(countPixels(i*h, j*w, h, w));
            //i would prefer:
            //array[i][j]=countPixels(i*h, j*w);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help! Sorry if this sounds stupid but why are you creating a 2D array to hold the height and width?

Comment: oh i made a mistake!!! it does not hold height and width, but it is the size of the array. other than a list or a vector you have to define, how large your array will be, at the point where you create it. so here a 10x10 matrix will be created

Comment: Thank you! What I did to fix it is a created a new variable called xh inside my countPixels method and set it equal to the initial x value, once I exited my first loop (Line 27) I set x equals to xh instead of back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

do it in two step:

**1:** sort each string:

```
public String sortString(String s1){
    char[] chars = s1.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String sorted = new String(chars);
    return sorted;   
}
```

**2:** put each of your string in an array and use:

```
Arrays.sort(stringArray);
```

Comment: ow, you are right, please see the edit history of question, I was in hurry and just seen the sample data and desired output without noticing and paying enough attention to question detail. anyway.